# Limit Comparison Test for Improper Integral

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

The question asks us to prove that the improper integral
$$
\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} dx
$$
is converget for all $n\geq0$, knowing that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n e^{-x} = 0 
$$
and advising not to use integration by parts.

I've already tried to compare it to $e^{-x}$ and $x^n$, but it always produces an inconclusive result, such as $+\infty$ or $0$. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sufficiently large $x$, we have
$$ x^n e^{-x} < e^{-x/2} $$
because this statement is equivalent to $x^n{e^{-x/2}}<1$ and we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^ne^{-x/2} = 0$. So we have
$$
\int_M^\infty x^n e^{-x}\operatorname d \! x \leq
\int_M^\infty e^{-x/2}\operatorname d \! x <\infty
$$
for some big $M$, and therefore original integral converges.

Answer (score 2):

The function is well behaving at $x\rightarrow 0$. For  $x\rightarrow \infty$, use the fact that it exists a value of x above which $x^n e^{-x}<x^{-2}$, the latter being well behaved at infinity (i.e. having finite integral when integrated say in the interval $[1,\infty]$). Such $x$ exists since $x^n e^{-x}<x^{-2}$ holds when $x^{n+2} e^{-x}<1$ which is clearly true for a sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: This answer matches the question better than mine, since it uses $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^ne^{-x} = 0$ explicitly